# MySQL query cache settings and high RAM ussage

Tags: mysql

Hello I have server with 120 GB of RAM and I have only 16 GB free. I think it's because of bad configuration of cache in my database. I'm getting information that ratio of free query cache memory to total query cache size is 11.9% and it should be around 80%.
My current settings:

```
query_cache_size = 16777216
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

Comment: That can't possibly account for it, that's a 16MB buffer. Use `ps` or whatever process listing tool is available to identify what process(es) are using that memory. You may also be confusing "free" memory as in completely unallocated with memory allocated for temporary kernel/disk buffers.

Comment: I can see using htop that /usr/sbin/mysqld have RES 107G and 85.2% MEM

Comment: There's some other configuration directive that's responsible then. This is q question better addressed to the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) but you should provide more detail if you do repost it.